# How to replace Tapestry's (version 5.4) default JQuery.js with a different version

Tags: jquery, tapestry

Tapestry's default JQuery.js doesn't work with some of the framework such as bootstrap. If two instances of JQuery are included there will be conflict as well? How to replace a default version with a specific JQuery version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the jQuery version by contributing an override for "jquery-library" in the JavaScriptStack.

There is an extensive example of an AppModule [available on gist](https://gist.github.com/benweidig/90547102c7dc4dc233485fbfcd1ca5da), the important part is this:

```
@Core
@Contribute(JavaScriptStack.class)
public static void overrideJquery(OrderedConfiguration<StackExtension> conf) {
    conf.override("jquery-library", StackExtension.library("classpath:META-INF/assets/jquery/jquery-X.X.X.min.js"));
}
```

---

jQuery also has a [built in solution](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for cases where the `$` variable is used by other libraries or multiple jQuery versions.

To quote their documentation:

> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version.

Comment: The above mentioned method worked well and I could replace the default JQuery script